# MS Access 2013 Online - How to add SQL?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have been using other versions of Access that allow for easy reporting and SQL. I am trying to use the MS Access 2013 Online Web App but I can't seem to use SQL. Where is the feature for querying with SQL in the online version?

Comment: This question is too vague. Please read [ask], then edit your question with details so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting [Access 2013 Web Apps](http://blogs.office.com/2012/07/30/get-started-with-access-2013-web-apps/) to be an imitation of the desktop application. You can publish your database to a certain extent to Office 365 via SharePoint. That does not mean you will have all the same functionality as the desktop version.

If you want to query with SQL, you will have to use the desktop version.

Alternatively, if you want "search" capability in Access 2013 Web Apps, you will have to create it in the forms. Microsoft explains here how create to [search queries in Access 2013 Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/build-and-publish-an-access-database-to-sharepoint-HA102435342.aspx#_Toc283211860).